# Why doesn't this POST request JSON match the expected argument in my Web API ActionResult?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Web API ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyActionResult(MyType data)
{
  ....
```

... where MyType is:

```
public class MyType
{
    public string myProperty1 { get; set; }
    public double? myProperty2 { get; set; }
    public double? myProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int? myProperty4 { get; set; }

    public bool myProperty5
    {
        get {
            return myProperty2.HasValue && myProperty3.HasValue;
        }
    }
}
```

.. and I'm sending the following in the body of my POST request using Postman:

```
{
    "myProperty1 ": "3109",
    "myProperty2": 45.10,
    "myProperty3": 45.10,
    "myProperty4": 1
}
```

This is hitting my ActionResult, but 'data' is empty. My JSON lints successfully. Why is the JSON not matching up to what my ActionResult expects?

Comment: Did you try passing myProperty5: true appended to your JSON payload?

Answer (score 0):

Doh! My request type needed to be JSON(application/JSON)